# Wordpress how to tell my css version

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

am developing wordpress theme, the wordpress automatically adds up my `style.css` but it assigns with version number which i don't now where it takes the value of version 
the below link is the one wordpress system adds to my head section of every page while the css version is 4.3.1.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwelve-style-css'  href='http://localhost/xyzwebsite/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/style.css?ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

and i want to be like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwelve-style-css'  href='http://localhost/xyzwebsite/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/style.css?ver=3.8.11' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to have in your `style.css`

```
/*
Theme Name: ThemeName
Version: 1.0.0
Author: yourname
Author URI: http://yourwebsite.com
Description: your description
Theme URI: your theme URL
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: random tags go here
*/
```

Right on top. Also in your `functions.php` file you'll need

```
<?php
define('THEME_NAME', 'ThemeName');
define('THEME_VERSION', '1.0.0');
```

And then just [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) it in functions.php with

```
wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), THEME_VERSION);
```

You can make it dependent on other stylesheets if you want in the array, and the theme version goes after it.

Comment: in the `THEME_VERSION` i have to use my expected css version

Comment: Well `THEME_VERSION` is something you change. It's a defined constant. Every time you update your theme, you need to change this in the `functions.php`, `style.css` and `readme.txt`

Comment: @dingo_d, in my case where do i mention my css version which is `3.8.11`

Comment: Look in your `functions.php` file. And see if you have `3.8.11` written in `wp_enqueue_style` where you enqueue your main stylesheet. Should look something like: `wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );` Check if there is any number. If not, just add it.